# Get parent rows where multiple child rows meet different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database I have two tables: `T_INDEX`, and `T_INDEXCALLER`. It's a one-to-many relationship. Each index record can have multiple callers (referenced by `IndexId`).

On my app's front-end, I have two search fields: Name, and Extension. Both of these fields reference the `T_INDEXCALLER` table. And in my search algorithm, I need to be able to "`and`" both of those fields. I need to return the `T_INDEX` records that have one or more child records where the "Name" matches, and that have one or more child records where the "Extension" matches.

This is the query I am currently using:

```
DECLARE @name varchar(100);
DECLARE @extension varchar(100);
SET @name = 'fox';
SET @extension = '9039';

SELECT *
FROM T_INDEX
WHERE T_INDEX.IndexId IN (SELECT IndexId FROM T_INDEXCALLER WHERE Name = @name)
AND T_INDEX.IndexId IN (SELECT IndexId FROM T_INDEXCALLER WHERE ExtensionNumber = @extension)
```

This works, but it's not very efficient. There are around 10 million index records, and even more caller records. Is there a way to re-write this search query using joins that will remove the need for the inner `SELECT`'s (and be more efficient)?

The problem I am running into is that when I re-write it with a join, I am only getting `T_INDEX` records that have a child record where both conditions match on the same child record. I want to get `T_INDEX` records that have a child record that matches the name condition, and a separate child record that matches the extension number condition.

Comment: You mean for a given `IndexId`, if there is one child record in `T_INDEXCALLER` that has `name = 'fox'` but `extension <> '9039' and another child record that has `name <> 'fox'` but `extension = '9039'`, you want both these child records to show up under the given `T_INDEX.IndexId`. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. However, it could also be within the same child record as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might start by writing this using `exists`:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM T_INDEX i
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM T_INDEXCALLER ic
              WHERE ic.Name = @name AND i.IndexId = ic.IndexId
             ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM T_INDEXCALLER ic
              WHERE ic.ExtensionNumber = @extension AND i.IndexId = ic.IndexId
             );
```

This can take advantage of an index `T_INDEXCALLER(indexId, Name, ExtensionNmber)`.

This may provide some speed up.  An alternative would be:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM T_INDEX i JOIN
     (SELECT ic.indexId
      FROM ((SELECT ic.indexId, 1 as priority
             FROM T_INDEXCALLER
             WHERE ic.ExtensionNumber = @extension
            ) UNION ALL
            (SELECT ic.indexId, 2 as priority
             FROM T_INDEXCALLER
             WHERE ic.Name = @name
            )
           ) ic
      GROUP BY ic.indexId
      HAVING MIN(priority) = 1 AND MAX(priority) = 2
     ) ic
     ON ic.indexId = i.indexId;
```

This can take advantage of indexes on `T_INDEXCALLER(name, indexId)`, `T_INDEXCALLER(ExtensionNumber, indexId)`, and (very importantly) `T_INDEX(indexId)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try. Is `EXISTS` faster than an inner `SELECT`?

Comment: @Gordon - Sorry if I am wrong but shouldn't you have OR condition(instead of AND) b/w your two EXIST queries?

Comment: Okay. Thanks @MattSpinks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you had applied the join logic, but based on your requirement, using an OR condition inside the `ON` clause should do the job.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM
  T_INDEX A INNER JOIN T_INDEXCALLER B
  ON A.IndexId = B.IndexId
  AND (B.Name = @name OR B.ExtensionNumber = @extension);
```

I can't speak for the execution speed, but you can use this one as an alternative if nothing works.

Comment: I'll give this one a try.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately this gives me the same result (both conditions have to be met on the same child record).